# explode in for loop in php

Tags: php, explode

```
<?php
$list    = file_get_contents('sitelist.txt');
$explode = explode("http://", $list);
$i       = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i < count($explode); $i++) {
    $filename = 'tost.txt';
    $fp       = fopen($filename, "a+");
    $write    = fputs($fp, $explode[$i] . "\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
echo "ok";
?>
```

It's not write or putting anything in tost.txt. what's the wrong here ?

Comment: Proper indentation and spacing is golden!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to open the output file before the loop and close it at the end=)

Comment: Try printing the contents of your `$explode` array just before the loop, does it contain anything. If not, then, well there's your answer.

Comment: is the directory/file you are writing to set with the correct permissions? (If not, php should give you an error, but it might be that you're not displaying errors)

Comment: @KristerAndersson
do u mention to add <code>print_r ($explode);</code> ?

Comment: @Jasper
Ya, file permission is ok. and no error is showing.

Comment: @slash-bang - I'm not following? Does your array contain any data?

Comment: Ya, i just get contents from sitelist.txt .
look, when i just only put  echo "$explode[$i]"; in loop. It is showing me the result.

Comment: `var_dump($list)` what does it look like ?? and what is your expected output ...

Comment: @Baba 
it is not executing problem. bcoz, when i just only put echo "$explode[$i]"; in for loop. It is showing me the result. 
I think it is problem in writing option.

Comment: Add `file_put_contents ( $filename , 'test');` at the end of your script and see if it is writing `test` to the file.

Comment: @slash-bang i don't debug that way ... i see so many unclear issues with your code `$explode = explode("http://", $list);` make me wonder what are you exploding and ignore new lines etc

Comment: @air4x 
It is writing "test" word with file_put_contents

Comment: @Baba 
i just wanna remove http:// from my sitelists .
and it is execute what i want. But it is not writing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some issues with your code

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($explode); $i++) {
    $filename = 'tost.txt';     <-------------------+
    $fp       = fopen($filename, "a+");-------------| All this should not be 
    $write    = fputs($fp, $explode[$i] . "\n");<---| in a loop
    fclose($fp); <----------------------------------+
}
```

All you are tying to do is the the same of this 2 lines

```
$list = file_get_contents('sitelist.txt');
file_put_contents('tost.txt', implode("\n", explode("http://", $list)));
```

Observation

Sill not sure why you have decided to use the following code

```
 explode("http://", $list)
```

This would

- Ignore new lines
- Return Invalid urls etc

You need to add your `var_dump($list)` and `expected output` if you are really going to have a working solution

Comment: Yes, that is the solution. 
i mean file_put_contents. 
but why open,write,close is not working ? any idea ?

Comment: As i said .. all you code is messed up and not in the proper position .. so many things can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown us. (Well, beyond skipping the first entry in the array and it being possible not to have more than a single entry in the array.) I have run your code on my server and it does output to `tost.txt`.

As such, the problem has to lie in factors outside the code, like whether or not the file permission is correct and whether or not file access is disabled on the server.

Comment: look, when i just only put echo "$explode[$i]"; in for loop. It is showing me the result. 

So, it is not value problem. although i tried to give $i to 0 value. But still not working

Comment: @slash-bang I have tried the code myself on my server and it works. Are you sure error reporting is on and are you sure your file permissions for `tost.txt` are correct? If those are correct, this is about the only thing that's left, which is why I posted it.

Comment: It is writing "test" word with file_put_contents by adding this code in script :  file_put_contents ( $filename , 'test'); 
That means writing is ok. And no error is showing me. 
i just tried with your solution . means, change value of $i to 0 . but not working